# How do I call a function in a different namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a function called `test`in `namespace buzz`.

From this test function i am calling another function called `dummy` which is inside `namespace example`.

I get the following error:

> Dummy is not a member of example.

Can you please tell me how to communicate between 2 different namespaces?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following code works with gcc (as expected).  Your problem must be with something that is not in the question.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace example
{
  void dummy() { std::cout << "Dummy\n"; }
}

namespace buzz
{
  void test() { example::dummy(); }
}

int main()
{
  buzz::test();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If the namespace is not nested, you should start navigating from the root one, i.e.:

Instead of:

```
example::dummy
```

Write:

```
::example::dummy
```

Comment: don't think so - all my code is within namespace `namespace myns {/*my code*/}`, and I am perfectly able to call 3rd party functions from their namespaces, starting with `std`. I think we should look at the code

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide code for this query. Otherwise **just** from your question, I guess you are making spelling error:

```
namespace example {
  void dummy() {}
}
namespace buzz {
  void test () { example::Dummy(); }  // capital 'D' instead of 'd' for dummy
}
```

Naturally, `Dummy is not a member of example.`  :))